# Better approach to include two curves in the flutter UI

Tags: flutter, user-interface, curve

I am completely new to flutter and I've a problem that how to include curves in the UI as in the image below if necessary.

[image: sample UI with two curves overriding quater of another]

I've tried this somewhat (not completed) using the ClipOval widget which is wraped inside the Positioned widget inside a Stack widget. Can anyone tell me is this the correct approach or any other better ones?

Here's What I tried so far.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});


final backgroundColor = const Color(0xFFAFEDB3);
final ellipse1 = const Color(0xB2F1FFEC);
final ellipse2 = const Color(0xff9FE3A4);



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login screen'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        // color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 154, 236, 156),
        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
          color: backgroundColor
,
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: -90,
              left: -75,
              height: 320,
              width: 450,
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  height: 200,
                  color: ellipse1,
                  child: const Text(
                    'Green',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Positioned(
              top: -10,
              right: -25,
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  height: 200,
                  color: ellipse2,
                  child: const Text(
                    'Green',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this package [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick Answer:

Use [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) to draw custom shapes.

If you have the image of your curve then try [this awesome tool](https://fluttershapemaker.com/#/) to convert your SVG image to dart custom paint code.

### Detailed Answer:

To achieve custom shape designs in Flutter, you can use any of the following approaches:

1. Using image assets directly (SVG or PNG).
2. Using a combination of ClipPath and Stacks (similar to other answers).
3. [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) to draw a shape for you.

**Note:** Before choosing the methods you should know your requirements, if performance and dynamically changing the shapes' color, position, or animating the shape is something you want then CustomPainter is the best choice.
Read [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/wjwl50/comment/ijl1xw3/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) to know why you should choose CustomPainter over the other two approaches.

[image]

Full conversation: [Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/wjwl50/is_custom_painter_more_performant_than_flutter/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: CustomPaint(
                size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 200),
                painter: CurvePainter(color: Colors.green),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: CustomPaint(
                size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 200),
                painter: CurvePainter(color: Colors.orange),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;

  CurvePainter({required this.color});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height * 0.5);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 0.25, size.height * 0.25, size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.5);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 0.75, size.height * 0.75, size.width, size.height * 0.5);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq5zp.png)

**In this code, I've used a `Stack` widget to overlay two curved shapes on top of each other at the top of the screen. The `Positioned` widget is used to position the curved shapes at the top of the screen. You can adjust the colors and shapes of the curves according to your design requirements.**

Answer (score 0):

usually to achieve this view all answers will use in common a **stack and a clipping methodology** *to create creative clips.*

look at the presentation code: (`Stack of Containers`).

```
import 'package:chat/utils/clippers/MyClipper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const ROUTE = 'HOME';
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            color: Colors.green.shade300,
          ),
          ClipPath(
            clipper: MyClipper(),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              color: Colors.green.shade100,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: -100,
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
            child: Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.1),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,

              ),
            ),

          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

and the clipper class which clips container, and only applied to the middle container (with color of transparent green).

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {

    double w = size.width;
    double h = size.height;
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, 0.75*h);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(.5*w,.8*h,w,.6*h);
    path.lineTo(w, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) =>false;

}
```

note: at the first use of clippers, it may be confusing but if you understand correctly how it works, all becomes easy.

the final result

[image]

Hope it helps you.